# Create a function generates random password in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, passwords, password-generator

I want to create a function which generates a random password for given length. It should generate at least 8 length password which includes at least 2 number, 3 letter, 3 special character like for example: **a8b*4/c1+**

I found some code and mixed it up but I couldn't do it properly Could anyone help me about how to create this function.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION random_password(@length ID)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(8)
    AS
    BEGIN
       -- Declare the variables here
       DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(8)
       DECLARE @BinaryData VARBINARY(8)
       DECLARE @CharacterData VARCHAR(8)
       DECLARE @randval VARCHAR(8)
       randval = CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)
    
       SELECT @BinaryData = randval
       FROM vRandom
     
       Set @CharacterData=cast ('' as xml).value ('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@BinaryData"))',
                       'varchar (max)')
       
       SET @Result = @CharacterData
       
       -- Return the result of the function
       RETURN @Result
    END
```

Comment: Is this for MySQL or SQL Server? These are two different dialects.

Comment: It is SQL Server.